# Amateur Z-Index Issues

Tags: html, css

I have a (hopefully) quick problem. I attempted to use z-index, but when I scroll the div with the index does not follow the page. CSS & HTML are below, hoping someone can help an amateur with this.
HTML:

```
    <!--If you would like to see the direct files, just ask!-->
<div id="head_div"> <center><p id="head_p"> Welcome, UoC Reader! -Jack P</p>   </center></div>
<div id="left_div_mainpage"></div>
<div id="right_div_mainpage"> </div>
<div id="footer"> </div>

#head_div {
  background-color: maroon;
  height: 90px;
 z-index: 1;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
   }
#head_p {
color: white;
font-family: Georgia;
font-size: 25px;
position: relative;
display: inline;
}
#left_div_mainpage { 
background-color: MidnightBlue;
height: 900px;
width: 150px;
float: left;
 }
#right_div_mainpage
```

And yes, the div is linked to the CSS using an online editor, I've heard that one before.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: What to you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 2):

If you want your #head_div to follow your page when you scroll, you need to add the position:fixed to your element :

```
#head_div {
    background-color: maroon;
    height: 90px;
    z-index: 1;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sLooza5q/

Comment: Thanks, this helped with this issue and I'll keep this in mind for the future.